# CKEditor can't decode image value from JSON which is generated by itself after saving

Tags: jquery, json, ckeditor

I am new to CKEditor, I paste a screenshot on the editor and successfully saved it on database. But when I want to retrieve it using ajax with json format result to set the value again inside the editor, screenshot image is not showing on the editor but it has a value when I put it in alert().

the value below from json result which is cannot decode by the ckeditor

<p><img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQYAAACHCAIAAAB7zGCiAAADR0lEQVR4nO3ZMU5jSRhG0d5T74bFeC1eBblXwhbISBAzyWBDg74OsAeke05kP7 SXvDfUtn 9Q8xLy8vz8/PT09Pj4 P9/f33/04P86v734A/m S2CSRI4lNEjmS2CSRI4lNEjmS2CSRI4lNEjmS2CSR8wOSOB1 3x0fvmv5X0giRxKbJHIksUki58pJnA6/zw6nDxffzO754uFwmekvLr8BSeRcNYnT4TzJp8PrBJ/eTfx/Ly93Phzv3tz5leU3IYmcmx2czvP7ZtA/fvjhzZWWX40kcq6cxMPx7nL0OU/q5ehz2do/nekvLr8BSeRcM4l3o/rZpJ53/E 3 S8uvw1J5FwziT  C3wc9MsNn30Z OLy25BEzlUPTpdzz93xdLx7N B//mT0eu/d8fi6zX9x U1IIucH/C/xo0kiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksUkiRxKbJHIksf0L2hcpkn2UQEoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></p>

Im putting the value in text editor using the code below

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(json.result);
```

How can I decode that encoded image inside ckeditor? Any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's a base64 encoded image, it's not related to json.
Maybe some part of your code is breaking part of it and that's why it can't be displayed correctly again, but instead of using base64 encoded images, you should upload them to your server.

You can use [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/ImagePaste-plugin-for-Firefox) (the version 1.0 is free and does just this task) to take care of the conversion